# How to capture a response after $_POST in php?

Tags: php, oop

So i have a file named instance.php that contains my class "listing".page 2 is sending
$_POST arguments to instance.php. instance.php in favor instantiates an object of "listing" and echos a unique id. i want page 2 to capture this id, and maybe even more than that.

The problem is that instance.php and page 2 do not live in the same server. I know how to handle oop in Java quiet well but i'm getting the feeling that in php it's not that straightforward. I'm pretty sure i'm missing something here.

Could you help me with suggesting a good design for my implementation requirement?

EDIT: To be clear, i'm searching for a way for two or more php files that don't live on the same server/domain to have this relationship.

Comment: page 2 is the page that sends the $_POST arguments with some data to instance.php

Comment: Can you post your code, so we can understand that what you're trying to do is what we think we're solving?  When you say "page 2 is sending $_POST arguments to instance.php", do you mean you're accessing page 2 in a browser and sending a <form> to instance.php?  Using normal HTTP interaction, or AJAX?  Or are you attempting for your PHP to accomplish this communication on the server side, using something like cURL or some other method of web service communication?

edit: to be clear, the first method doesn't sound like what you want, the others can be made to do what it seems like you want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you insist on using POST for interaction ( which is kinda strange choice ), then you will have to use [cULR](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) to facilitate it.

The other way would be to use [`file_get_contents()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) function. That would limit you to using only GET method:

```
// in your Page2
$val = 12345;
$data = file_get_contents("http://external.site.foo/instance.php?param={$val}");
var_dump($data);

// in the instance.php
echo $_GET['param'] , '-verified';
```

Comment: i have about 20 parameters... i'm not sure it's possible to use GET with so many characters.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to install and use [cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php). The code in **page 2** will look something like:

```
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://example.com/instance.php");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "key1=value1&key2=value2");

$id = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);
```

If you want to retrieve more than the ID, I would suggest making an `array()` on `instance.php` and serializing it:

```
echo serialize(array("id" => 1, "name" => "John"));
```

and unserializing it in **page 2**:

```
...
$arr = unserialize(curl_exec($ch))
...
```